# How to use sync.WaitGroup in pipeline

Tags: go, waitgroup

I'm trying to implement a pipeline in Go and there was a problem that the program exits the main goroutine before the rest of the goroutines are finished.

Please, help fix this case **using wait groups**.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    c1 := make(chan string)
    c2 := make(chan string)

    go sender(c1)
    go removeDuplicates(c1, c2)
    go printer(c2)

    wg.Wait()
}

func sender(outputStream chan string) {
    wg.Add(1)
    wg.Done()

    for _, v := range []string{"one", "one", "two", "two", "three", "three"} {
        outputStream <- v
    }

    close(outputStream)
}

func removeDuplicates(inputStream, outputStream chan string) {
    wg.Add(1)
    wg.Done()

    temp := ""

    for v := range inputStream {
        if v != temp {
            outputStream <- v
            temp = v
        }
    }

    close(outputStream)
}

func printer(inputStream chan string) {
    wg.Add(1)
    wg.Done()

    for v := range inputStream {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}
```

When I used time.Sleep in this case, the program worked successfully.

Comment: You're misusing wait groups. `Add` must be called _before_ you start the goroutine, and `Done` must be called _at the very end_ of the goroutine. Also, a package-level wait-group variable is awkward; instead, declare it in `main` and pass a pointer to it to the functions that need it.

Comment: You don't need a WaitGroup. Just don't run printer in a separate goroutine.

Comment: @Peter, I need waitGroup for process understanding

Comment: if you want to use `WaitGroup` then use it only in the last element of the pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

The first rules of working with wait groups: don't call `Add()` from a goroutine you're going to wait for. It is possible, that `Wait()` will be called *before* `Add()`, which is not what you expect. The second rule: call `Done()` in the end, not in the beginning. So, the fix would be:

```
func main() {
    c1 := make(chan string)
    c2 := make(chan string)

    wg.Add(3)

    go sender(c1)
    go removeDuplicates(c1, c2)
    go printer(c2)

    wg.Wait()
}

func sender(outputStream chan string) {
    defer wg.Done()

    for _, v := range []string{"one", "one", "two", "two", "three", "three"} {
        outputStream <- v
    }

    close(outputStream)
}

// etc for other two functions
```

Comment: I really appreciate it!

Comment: The second rule is "don't declare a wait-group variable at package level".

Comment: @jub0bs I guess, that falls into a more generic rule of not using global variables when possible.

Comment: @jub0bs, is better to pass declared waitGroup to functions?

Comment: @sv_dev you need to pass the pointer to the wait group, because wait groups cannot be copied.